# HTML Grab picture from static URL - From, input

Tags: html, forms, image, input, upload

Okay, so the thing is, I have a camera connected localy. Every time I make a request for the static URL it will always provoid a new picture.
So basicly, the picture is a static input...

I would like to be able to click on a lable (My input is hidden (CSS)) to upload the picture. Futher more, it will go into a editor. I just don't know how to grab the picture from a url.

Snippet is a example, with a static picture (Not the one I will be using localy)
I just need to grap the picture from a input, within my form.

(This is to make ID badges, a localy network setup)

```html
<form action="#" method="POST" role="form">
  <input type="file" acccept="images/" class="form-control" id="uploaded-img" accept="image/*">
    <div class="upload-button">
      <label for="uploaded-img">
       <span class="label-text">Velg Bilde</span><span class="upload-icon"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i></span>
      </label>
     </div>

  <input type="text" value="http://nortek.media/1.jpg" class="form-control-2" id="uploaded-img-2">
    <div class="upload-button">
      <label for="uploaded-img-2">
        <span class="label-text">Ta Bilde</span><span class="upload-icon"><i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i></span>
      </label>
    </div> 
</form>
```

Thanks for help in advanced!

Comment: This is what the editor looks like, the arrow indicates the button to grab the static picture from URL, that I don't know how to make: [Picture](http://nortek.media/TheOption.png)